# nested select - multi part identifier not bound error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, nested-select

I have written the following query, but I am getting a  multi part identifier not bound error, as I am trying to filter the sub query, using values from the first inner join, from outside the sub select.

```
SELECT runners.id,  wins
FROM dbHorseRacing.dbo.historic_runners as runners
inner join dbHorseRacing.dbo.historic_races as races on races.race_id = runners.race_id 
inner join (
    select ru.runner_id, count(*) as wins
    FROM dbHorseRacing.dbo.historic_runners as ru
    inner join dbHorseRacing.dbo.historic_races as ra on ra.race_id = ru.race_id 
    where ru.runner_id = runners.runner_id
    and ra.meeting_date < races.meeting_date
    and ru.finish_position = 1
    group by ru.runner_id
) w on w.runner_id = runners.runner_id
```

its the following two line that are causing the problem:

```
where ru.runner_id = runners.runner_id
        and ra.meeting_date < races.meeting_date
```

I have tried to write this query in other ways but with no sucess, I have seen other people using nested select, referencing identifiers from outside the nested select...

Is what I am trying to do generally wrong as a principle? If so, is there another way I could achieve it?

I have tried finding an answer and would really appreciate any help!

Laura

Comment: how you get runners and races inside subquery?

Comment: You want a kind of running sum.  For each runners.id and races, how many times he won previous races?

Comment: Yes exaclty! a running sum.

Comment: Zaynul - thats the problem I dont seem to be able to...

Comment: when you will use corelated sub-query in that you can use outer query inside of subquery but here you do just  with subquery

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
SELECT runners.id, (
    select count(*)
    FROM dbHorseRacing.dbo.historic_races
    where historic_races.runner_id = runners.runner_id
    and historic_races.meeting_date < races.meeting_date
    and ru.finish_position = 1
) wins
FROM dbHorseRacing.dbo.historic_runners as runners
inner join dbHorseRacing.dbo.historic_races as races on races.race_id = runners.race_id
```

Comment: Thank you so much Daniel, I have just tried this and it work perfectly! Thanks again, I have lost loads of time over this.

Answer (score 0):

below query will work    as you not shared your output so i just edited query workable version

```
SELECT runners.id,  wins
    FROM dbHorseRacing.dbo.historic_runners as runners
    inner join dbHorseRacing.dbo.historic_races as races on races.race_id = runners.race_id 
    inner join (
        select ru.runner_id, count(*) as wins
        FROM dbHorseRacing.dbo.historic_runners as ru
        inner join dbHorseRacing.dbo.historic_races as ra on ra.race_id = ru.race_id 
       where ru.finish_position = 1
        group by ru.runner_id
    ) w on w.runner_id = runners.runner_id
```

Comment: Thank you Zaynul,  I have just implemented the version from Daniel, but thank you. :)